# Can't install networkx for python 3.4

Tags: python, networkx

After 3 days of trying to install networkx for python 3.4, I am on the verge of giving up and I've decided to seek for help from some of you people who had some experience with this perhaps.

I managed to install networkx with easy_install or pip_install (I don't even remember anymore of how many times I've tried to install it all), but when I try to compile the very first, most basic piece of code (found in a tutorial):

```
import networkx as nx;

Test = nx.Graph();
Test.add_node("Test");
nx.draw(Test, node_size=900, node_color="blue");
```

I get an error: *ImportError: No module named 'numpy'*
When I try to install numpy with *easy_install numpy* it starts the download and installation process normally but then it shows this error:
*Microsoft Visual C++ 10 is required*

Is this referred to MV C++ 1- redistributable? I've downloaded it and tried to install it but it shouts out an error that I already have a newer version of it so I don't need it...

So my questions would be:
1.Can networkx module be installed for python 3.4 at all?
2.If so, do I need anything else besides networkx zip/installer and python 3.4 for it to work? (I've literally found 4 sources that all claim different requirement information about networkx!)

I would really appreciate any help, as I feel completely lost and discouraged about any further use of python.

Comment: If you're on Windows, it will be _much_ easier for you to use Chris Gohlke's binaries than to try to build numpy yourself: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Configuring a compiler on windows is more work than it's worth if you don't already have one in working order.

Comment: Only three projects there still have `.exe` installers available. The rest are `.whl` files now, which have to be installed with `pip` or similar tools.

Comment: for sure networkx can be installed for python 3.4 - it states in the online documentation "To use NetworkX you need Python 2.7, 3.2 or later." so no problem on that side

Comment: found here: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/install.html

Comment: Thank you all for giving me great answers! I really appreciate them all! In the end I ended up choosing Aric's suggestion - Anaconda. It works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which operating system you are using but by referencing *Microsoft Visual C++* I'm going to say *Windows*.  In that case the simplest way to get a functioning scientific Python computing environment is to install one of the packaged distributions.  Two good choices are Anaconda https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/ and Enthought Canopy https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/

NetworkX definitely works with Python3.4 https://travis-ci.org/networkx/networkx

Comment: I want to thank you Aric for giving me a great answer and saving me from quitting python :) I've installed anaconda (though not on my PC cause I was away) and it worked perfectly! :) It was quite simple to set it all up and now I can finally start working on what I wanted! I'll never understand what stops the rest of the developers/companies to make easy and straightforward installers such as anaconda, when they do way more complicated stuff on daily basis anyway.

Also I apologize for not specifying the OS I use, thanks for assuming it on your own and giving me a great answer right away!