# Can networkx select specific columns from csv data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

Lets say i have a data.csv file with the following:

```
a 1 2 45
b 2 3 24
c 4 5 98
d 5 6 12
```

And i want my nodes and, I guess, edges to be just columns 2 and 3

So it outputs somehting like this:

[image]

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: I'm trying to only use columns 2 and 3 from the data.csv file to output something similar to what's in the image, i just wanted to know if there was a way networkx can do that, because read_edgelist() doesnt accept my current file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use pandas to read your .csv file in as a df, then perform a list comprehension to extract each row into a format readable by the networkx library.

The following code is partly adapted from: [Drawing a network with nodes and edges in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103119/drawing-a-network-with-nodes-and-edges-in-python3)

... with modifications for a directed graph in a circular layout, with the nodes, edges, and weights being the columns of your df

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'nodes': [1,2,4,5], 'edges': [2,3,5,6], 'weights': [45,24,98,12]})

# each edge is a tuple of the form (node, edge/node, {'weight': weight})
edges = [(x, y, {'weight': z}) for x, y, z in zip(df['nodes'], df['edges'], df['weights'])]

# a directed graph has arrows pointing to edges
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from(edges)

# create a circular layout
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# draw the nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_size=300)

# draw the labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos, font_size=15,font_family='sans-serif')

# draw the edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos, edgelist=edges, arrowstyle = '-|>', width=1)

# add weights
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos, edge_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: circular directed graph]